# Force load desired dpi drawables according to screen size

Tags: android, drawable, dpi, screen-size

I have 4 sets of images

```
Resolutions        DPI      Directory
240 x 320          120dpi - drawable-ldpi
320 x 480          160dpi - drawable-mdpi
480 x 800          240dpi - drawable-hdpi
1280x 800          320dpi - drawable-xhdpi
```

But when I tested it at ASUS transformer with resolution `1280x800 and DPI 224`.
It loaded graphics from drawable-hdpi.

If I will add another folder with name drawable-xlarge, It will load desired images but it will increase the size of application as well.

My questions are as follows

1 - What is the best practice to support all screen sizes and DPI?

2 - Is there any way to force load drawable of particular DPI w.r.t screen size?

3 - What is the solution recommended for my problem without replicating the graphics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But when I tested it at ASUS transformer with resolution 1280x800 and dpi 224. It loaded graphics from drawable-hdpi.

That is because the ASUS Transformer is an `-hdpi` device. Hence, it is working properly.

> What is the best practice to support all screen sizes and dpi?

Usually, images only vary based on density, and so your current structure is fine.

If you elect to have images that vary both on screen size *and* density, you will need to make more directories (e.g., `res/drawable-xlarge-hdpi/`) and images for the

> Is there any way to force load drawable of perticular dpi w.r.t screen size?

Density and screen size have nothing to do with one another.

> What is the solution recommended for my problem without replicating the graphics?

According to your "question", you do not have a problem. Hence, there is no recommendation for your non-problem.

Comment: I know that but creating more images will increase application size.

Comment: @CommonsWare By the way is it normal that 224 dpi considered by the operating system as high? Do you know if it takes the closest value to specify the kind of density?

Comment: @SyedMuhammadUmair: So? You are the one deciding to have different icons for different screen sizes.

Comment: @teoREtik: The manufacturer chooses the density bucket, not the OS.

Comment: @CommonsWare So it is set programmatically by the vendor, isn't it?

Comment: I am looking for a way to load xhdpi images for xlarge, one way is to create res/drawable-xlarge-hdpi/ as you said. Is there any other way?

Comment: I can create 4x4=16 set of graphics for all screen sizes and all the dpi. But it will increase the size of application. Or I have to deploy one build for each screen size.

Comment: @teoREtik: "So it is set programmatically by the vendor, isn't it?" -- I think it is in a configuration file versus Java code, but I am not an expert to that depth on the internals.

Comment: @SyedMuhammadUmair: You are welcome to use resource aliases to have the same image file be represented in multiple resource directories. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources

Comment: @CommonsWare I need to fetch `xxxhdpi` images for `Nexus 5x`  [xxhdpi], is it possible? the reason is images are showing small compare to `Nexus 5` [xxhdpi]

Comment: @KishoreJethava: I do not know of a way to do that off the top of my head, sorry